# Valgrind (below main), how to get full stack trace?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, stack-trace, valgrind

I have the following stack trace from valgrind. But it does not give me the full stack trace.

```
==2433== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==2433==    at 0x402B06C: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==2433==    by 0x43F345B: av_freep (mem.c:172)
==2433==    by 0x5A6F4D2: (below main) (libc-start.c:226)
```

In gdb, I *think* I get the same error:

```
#5  0xb7c1345c in av_free (ptr=<optimized out>) at libavutil/mem.c:172
#6  av_freep (arg=0x88a2e48) at libavutil/mem.c:181
#7  0xb7c165c8 in av_opt_free (obj=0x88a2ba0) at libavutil/opt.c:787
#8  0xb6b56efc in avcodec_close (avctx=0x88a2ba0) at libavcodec/utils.c:1675
#9  0x0808a3e0 in encode_lavc_finish (ctx=0x8343a40) at encode_lavc.c:288
#10 0x08077d0b in exit_player_with_rc (mpctx=0x8313058, how=EXIT_EOF, rc=0)
at mplayer.c:705
#11 0x0806ced0 in main (argc=8, argv=0xbffff374) at mplayer.c:4771
```

But with the gdb trace goes all the way up to `main()`.

How do I get the full stack trace in valgrind, is at all possible?

Comment: Have you tried --logfile=file-basename option and see the log generated?

Comment: @Vincenzo Maggio it gives me the exact same output.

Comment: Have you read this: http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.unhelpful ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In gdb, I think I get the same error

You didn't get an *error* in GDB. You got a breakpoint on `av_free`, but surely `av_free` is called a *lot*, and you've provided no evidence that this particular call is the one that triggers Valgrind error.

It's very likely that some *other* call to `av_free` is in fact triggering the Valgrind error, and it's also very likely that that call is executing from `atexit` handler, the Valgrind stack is *in fact* a full stack trace.

If you are using a recent version of Valgrind, you can actually debug the program running under Valgrind with `--vgdb-error=1`, and attach GDB *exactly* where the problem happens. Documentation [here](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver).

Comment: Yep, I just discovered attaching a debugger. Also thanks to @Vincenzo who pointed me to the faq. When attaching gdb, the stack trace is exactly the same as using gdb without valgrind.